# Substitute for whipped topping?

Tags: substitutions

I know that when a recipe calls for "whipped topping" it's code for [Cool Whip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_Whip). I am not a fan of Cool Whip, but want to make a recipe which calls for it. Is there a substitute that I can make or purchase that isn't totally artificial?

Trying to substitute Cool Whip in this recipe:

Banana-Berry Frozen Yogurt Bars

10-½ Honey Maid Honey Graham's, broken into quarters (42 rectangles)

½ cup sliced fresh strawberries
½ cup chopped bananas
¼ cup blueberries

1 cup vanilla nonfat Greek-style yogurt
1 cup thawed frozen reduced-fat whipped topping

1. Line 9-inch square pan with foil, with ends of foil extending over sides. Arrange half the graham pieces, in 3 rows of 7 pieces each, on bottom of pan.
2. Pulse fruits in blender just until blended. (Some chunks should remain.) Spoon fruit into medium bowl; stir in yogurt and whipped topping. Spread over graham pieces in pan; top with remaining graham pieces, aligning over graham pieces on bottom layer.
3. Freeze 4 hours. Use foil handles to lift dessert from pan; cut between grahams into 21 bars. Let stand 5 minutes before serving.

Comment: Could you please post the recipe, or a link to it? It's a lot easier to tell what kind of substitutes will work with a recipe.

Comment: @Jefromi added the recipe as requested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could whip your own cream. Use 1/3 of the amount of heavy cream as cool whip, and whip with a splash of vanilla extract and a pinch of sugar to taste, either by hand or with a mixer. If a recipe calls for 1 cup of "whipped topping", you would start with 1/3 cup of heavy cream which whips up to 1 cup.